# How to get values from sql database and access them from php session

Tags: php, sql, session

I have been trying now for 2 days to access the sql database and get the values for "username" and "gender" (successful), and put them into session (unsuccessful). I don't know how to modify the code to make it work, despite looking all through this site, looking at examples, searching offsite in vain.
I am very new to coding, and any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank-you.

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "11111111";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbtest";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id_user, username, gender FROM fgusers3";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> id_user: ". $row["id_user"]. " - username: ". $row["username"]. " - gender: " . $row["gender"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

$_SESSION[$key]=$value;
$_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
$_SESSION['gender']=$row['gender'];
echo $_SESSION["username"] . ".<br>";
echo $_SESSION["gender"] . ".";
?>
```

Comment: As you appear to be getting more than one row from your table, how do you want these multiple items represented in Session

Comment: I just need from the table 2 rows thats all, username, and gender.  Eventually I want to take those values and have them in url.

Comment: `$conn->close();` that should be at the bottom of your code. `$row['x']` will no longer have any value.

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting more than one row, the data must be stored in the SESSION in some sort of array, So here is one suggestion that should create the seesion like this.

```
$_SESSION['usernames'][0] = 'Fred'
$_SESSION['usernames'][1] = 'Frederica'

$_SESSION['genders'][0] = 'Male'
$_SESSION['genders'][1] = 'Female'
```

The code mods

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "11111111";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbtest";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id_user, username, gender FROM fgusers3";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> id_user: ". $row["id_user"]. " - username: ". $row["username"]. " - gender: " . $row["gender"] . "<br>";

        // Add to the session inside the loop

        $_SESSION['usernames'][] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['genders'][] = $row['gender'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Possibly a cleaner solutions would be

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> id_user: ". $row["id_user"]. " - username: ". $row["username"]. " - gender: " . $row["gender"] . "<br>";

        // Add to the session inside the loop

        $_SESSION['users'][] = ['username' =>$row['username'],
                                'gender'] => $row['gender']
                               ];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly for your help I am still just getting the database data only though.

Comment: Look at session by doing a `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: POST array contains: Array ( ) Session contains: Array ( [username] => [gender] => [usernames] => Array ( [0] => dan [1] => dan ) [genders] => Array ( [0] => male [1] => male ) ).  Thank you very much.  Please bear with me I am trying to be slow and deliberate on this.

Comment: Loose your original code that was trying to set session. Then I would hope you will see that data as intended only

Comment: I need the Array to output like this:  POST array contains: Array ( ) Session contains: Array ( [name_of_user] => dan [email_of_user] => someperson@gmail.com [usr_87601d2e30].  How can I change the code for this output?

Comment: Thanks!!!  I finally got it to work, with your help, RiggsFolly and Funk Forty Niner!!!

Comment: @funkFortyNiner Looks like we should share the reps for this answer. Oh wait... Answer not accepted and no Upvote either! I will allocate you 50% of nothing

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that is working:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id_user, username, gender FROM fgusers3";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        "<br> id_user: ". $row["id_user"]. " - username: ". $row["username"]. " - gender: " . $row["gender"] . "<br>";


       $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
       $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```